# Security (Authentication) in oData services

Tags: android, security, authentication, odata, azure-sql-database

My Database is located at SQLAzure and i am trying to use oData to get records. I have used oData4j java library as i am developing android application. Everything is working fine.

I am able retrieve data from SQLAzure using oData4j library but the problem is ...

If someone gets my SVC file URL, so they can easily get my database and play with it. so i want to put authentication so that only authorized  person can retrieve data and work with it.

How can i achieve this. I have not created oData PRoducer or SVC file. All this thing is done by SQLAzure.

thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a series of blog posts about OData services and authentication: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the ACS access keys? I haven't personally used them, but this is meant to provide a form of federated identity so that you can manage who can consume the oData service.  ACS is a service provided by the Azure platform.

Since you can map each ACS to a specific database user, you have complete freedom to ensure only authorized people can access you data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following post. This has pointers to odata and authentication related blog posts from Astoria Team:
http://kashyapas.com/2011/05/odata-and-authetication/

That should give you pointers

Answer (score 0):

The sample application for Windows Azure Toolkit for Android might help.

[How to: Use the Sample Android Application in the Windows Azure Toolkit for Android](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj136812)

https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-android